# Bounded atomic counter using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, atomic

I was trying to design a simple bounded atomic counter and was wondering if my thinking is correct. Mongodb has an operation called findAndModify(). This operation takes a query. If the query is something like:

```
 findAndModify: "counter",
 query: { count: { $le: 10 } },
 update: { $inc: { count: 1 } }
```

...would this only increment and return the counter if count is less than 10? If so my code could basically run this, and if no document is returned my code can assume the counter is at max value?

Also, is this guaranteed to increment correctly if multiple processes perform the same action? i.e. while count = 0, operation A and operation B both attempt a findAndModify() at the same time, operation A will increment count to 1 and operation B will increment count to 2? Or is it possible both operations will increment the counter to 1?

Answer (score 0):

`findAndModify` operation is atomic as long as a single document is considered. So, increment will only happen if the filter holds, even if there are multiple processes executing the same update. In your case if many processes run the query at the same time, only the first ten will update the value and the others will not match.